# can we select specific wifi using hardcoded password for android devices

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to connect to a specific Wifi selected from the list and I want to hard code the password in my app.
Is it possible in android devices that an app can connect to a specific Wifi network and provide the password?
Is there an API for this?

Comment: Check out the docs from Google: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the docs from Google: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html